# Mock/Spy sessionStorage in jasmine when executing tests in Nodejs and not Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, spying

I was trying to spyOn sessionStorage object in jasmine.
I've written the following code to achieve spying on real sessionStorage

```
   fakeStore = {
      employee: {
        id: 123456,
        emailId: 'admin@domain.com',
        role: 'admin'
      }
    };

    fakeStorage = {
      getItem: (key: string): string => fake Store[key]
    };

spyOn(sessionStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(fakeStorage.getItem);
```

But after encountering the error `sessionStorage is undefined`
I suddenly realised that I'm executing the jasmine tests on NodeJs environment rather than browser.
Since there is not such thing called sessionStorage in NodeJs global context test case failed.

I have to either run this test alone in browser or completely ignore.
Is there any way I can simulate browser's global `window` context as NodeJs's `global`

I've tried to add sessionStorage into `global` of nodejs,but typescript didn't let me....

How to solve this ?

Comment: the question is not about how to mock localStorage,instead it is how to run browser related unit tests(which has dependency related to browser's objects such as window,location etc) on node.js

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
spyOn(window.sessionStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(()=>{})
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works.