# How to spyon session storage in angular jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, codecov

How to write the spyon for session storage ?

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.role=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser))['role'];

}
```

Comment: Instead test the role property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351377/mock-spy-sessionstorage-in-jasmine-when-executing-tests-in-nodejs-and-not-browse

Comment: @jai, i tried but undefined

Comment: @SivaguruNathan just before the test try to set a mock role in the session storage and then assert